# How to redirect a user with specific "ROLE" to a specific page after login in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a new user role named **student_role** I want to redirect the user with this role to form page(which I created from wp front end) when he logs in.

I tried peter login redirect plugin but failed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this :

```
function rohil_login_redirect_based_on_roles($user_login, $user) {

    if( in_array( 'student_role',$user->roles ) ){
        exit( wp_redirect('Your page link goes here' ) );
    }   
}

add_action( 'wp_login', 'rohil_login_redirect_based_on_roles', 10, 2);
```

**Explanation**

If you look at the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_login), you will find that `wp_login` provides two parameter: 1) `$user_login` which will return a string and 2) `$user` will return an object containing all the details.

But you need to make sure that you also pass **priority** to that parameters otherwise It will give you an error.

If you want to see what data are into that parameter, you can run below code for **learning purpose** only.

```
function rohil_login_redirect_based_on_roles($user_login, $user) {

    var_dump($user); // Will give you an object
    var_dump($user_login); //Will give you a string
    die();

}
add_action( 'wp_login', 'rohil_login_redirect_based_on_roles', 10, 2);
```

**Make sure you delete above code from `functions.php` after checking what data it contains**

So as you can `$user` object contains **roles** which shows current logged in user's role. So I simple checked that `if($user->roles[0] === 'student_role')` if current logged in user is having `student_role` then `wp_redirect('Your page link goes here')` redirect them to some page.

Let me know if you have any doubt.

Comment: Can u please explain ur code as well. I mean y u passed parameters to function. and please tell y u used action hook like add_action( 'wp_login', 'rohil_login_redirect_based_on_roles', 10, 2);

Comment: Excellent...  and please tell what does this do "add_action( 'wp_login', 'rohil_login_redirect_based_on_roles', 10, 2);"

Comment: Its simply an action. If you ask me what is action I would say in simple words that It is process that user/developer can do after finishing that action.
So here it would be like after `wp_login` action(which is for user login) call `rohil_login_redirect_based_on_roles` function. So it will call that function and do the stuff that are written in that function.

Comment: Clear.. (10, 2); and these two are priorities of what?

Comment: Its the priority for the execution of the function associated with the `action`. To understand better, take an example: Suppose you have two function having same action `wp_login`, how would it decide that which function should be executed first and which should be second. So if priority is there, it will execute in that particular order.

Comment: Thanks. I will be posting new thread in a while hope u will help